# PIL vs Python-GD for crop and resize

Tags: python, ajax, gd, python-imaging-library, seadragon

I am creating custom images that I later convert to an image pyramid for Seadragon AJAX.  The images and image pyramid are created using PIL.  It currently take a few hours to generate the images and image pyramid for approximately 100 pictures that have a combined width and height of about 32,000,000 by 1000 (yes, the image is very long and narrow).  The performance is roughly similar another algorithm I have tried (i.e. [deepzoom.py](http://github.com/openzoom/deepzoom.py)).  I plan to see if python-gd would perform better due to most of its functionality being coded in C (from the GD library). I would assume a significant performance increase however I am curious to hear the opinion of others. In particular the resizing and cropping is slow in PIL (w/ Image.ANTIALIAS). Will this improve considerable if I use Python-GD?

Thanks in advance for the comments and suggestions.

EDIT: The performance difference between PIL and python-GD seems minimal. I will refactor my code to reduce performance bottlenecks and include support for multiple processors. I've tested out the python 'multiprocessing' module. Results are encouraging.

Comment: Seadragon looks very cool. Can the task be split over multiple processes or multiple computer?

Comment: It can be split. I was hoping to avoid this because it requires some significant re-factoring of my code, but looks like it may be unavoidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL is mostly in C.

Antialiasing is slow. When you turn off antialiasing, what happens to the speed?

Comment: Actually tried this after I posted. It is much quicker using BILINEAR and give comparable results aesthetically. Also, the performance of the resize method is comparable between PIL and python-GD (10% difference in speed).

Answer (score 0):

VIPS includes a [fast deepzoom creator](http://libvips.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/making-deepzoom-zoomify-and-google-maps.html). I timed `deepzoom.py` and on my machine I see:

```
$ time ./wtc.py 
real    0m29.601s
user    0m29.158s
sys     0m0.408s
peak RES 450mb
```

where `wtc.jpg` is a 10,000 x 10,000 pixel RGB JPG image, and `wtc.py` is using [these settings](https://github.com/openzoom/deepzoom.py/blob/develop/examples/helloworld/helloworld.py).

VIPS is around three times faster and needs a quarter of the memory:

```
$ time vips dzsave wtc.jpg wtc --overlap 2 --tile-size 128 --suffix .png[compression=0]
real    0m10.819s
user    0m37.084s
sys     0m15.314s
peak RES 100mb
```

I'm not sure why sys is so much higher.